# Contact face vs. mating face

Tags: connector, pinout

I'm a bit unsure which side is the contact face and which is the mating face. In my opinion, the red side is the mating face and the blue side is the contact face. Could you confirm or refute this for me?  I'm considering this from the perspective of pin numbering.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fun part is that both pins and sockets can be referred to as contacts.  One convention dictates the side that resembles a pin in the metal, (regardless of whether the plastic on it inserts into another) be called the male.  My convention is to test this nonsense and make isometric views (or pictures) of the connectors with pin labels.

Comment: You need to first be sure if that receptacle is called a "male" (because it has contact pins) or "female" (because it is the receptacle with pins, and obviously the plug with holes for the pins goes into the receptacle with pins).

Comment: https://www.harwin.com/products/M80-8420445/ this is the male and this one is a female: https://www.harwin.com/products/M80-1010498S/

Answer (score 1):

The pin #1 is on the right side of your photo based on:

- Contacts are the metal conductors that touch each other in mating connectors
- General convention is that the contact resembling a pin (rather than a socket) goes in the male connector, regardless of whether the plastic for it inserts into another
- They are using this convention. By it, you have photographed the male; they drew the corners (those black filled triangles) in their imaging (this would be empty space on the female)

Their statement can thus be read as:
"They represent male connectors [like the one in your photo], shown looking onto the contact face [as if your line of sight, away from your eyeball, would be the direction the female would need to travel to make electrical contact]."

The following sentence just states something obvious, referring to the contact face of the female as mating to the male. "For female connectors looking on the mating face [that mates with the male face of the previous sentence], the numbering will [if we want to keep numbers of contacting buses the same], be mirrored."

[image: Pins numbered "4 3 2 1" Left to Right]

Comment: This is correct but (not your fault @Abel) obviously confusing from a terminology standpoint. In practice, a perspective drawing of the connector in question with the pins numbered can reduce the ambiguity.

Comment: Yup if it weren't confusing, it wouldn't cause this kind of questioning, and I wouldn't need to rationale them drawing corners.

Comment: How sure are you? I'm still not entirely convinced. The connector on my board is male, as seen in the lines in the comment. Furthermore, it states, "They represent male connectors, shown looking onto the contact face," meaning from the contact face side, in which case pin 1 should be all the way to the left, right?

Comment: As sure as I can get from the info provided.  1 as pictured is on the right per A1.1's 4-way picture.

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion, the red side is the mating face and the blue side is the contact face.

You are somewhat correct:

- Red: *mating face* because it's the face that is pressed against the mate when mated
- Blue: *termination side* because it's the side that is terminated to wiring (in this case, a PCB)

You called the blue side "contact face" which is slightly incorrect because the contacts are both terminated (blue end) and mated (red end). "Termination" is not ambiguous because is occurs only on the termination side, not on the mating face.

> I'm considering this from the perspective of pin numbering.

As your picture shows the mating face, therefore pin 1 is on the right.